# Object Lengths not Matching Up

Tags: javascript, json

I output the length of an object in two different ways and it leads to two different responses:

```
console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions.length);
console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions);
```

Outputs:

```
3
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
length: 9
```

Any idea why I'm getting two different lengths? The appData.questions appears to be inheriting objects from other objects for whatever reason.

Here's the JSON:

```
var appData = {
    "HomeGateway": {
        "company": "",
        "title": {
            "english": "",
            "spanish": "",
            "russian": "",
            "otherlanguage": ""
        },
        "language": "english",
        "pressOKQuestion": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Press ",
                "spansih": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " to move to the next question",
                "spanish": "\" to move to the next question",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "pressOKMessage": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Press ",
                "spansih": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " to move on",
                "spanish": "\" to move to the next question",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "pressUpDown": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Please press ",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "middle": {
                "english": " or ",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " on your remote control to select",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "questions": [{
            "url": "/question/1",
            "question": {
                "english": "Have you talked to your doctor today?",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "view": "views/question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/2",
            "answers": [{
                "id": 1,
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Yes",
                    "spanish": "Si",
                    "russian": ""
                }
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "No",
                    "spanish": "No",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "message": "/message/3"
            }]
        }, {
            "url": "/question/2",
            "question": {
                "english": "On a scale of 0-10, how bad is your pain today?",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446585749_Doctor_Consultation.png",
            "iconSrc": "Broken Arm",
            "view": "views/question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/3",
            "answers": [{
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Low",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "1-2"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Medium",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "3-4"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "High",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "5-8",
                "message": "/message/4"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Very High",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "9-10",
                "message": "/message/4"
            }]

        }, {
            "url": "/question/3",
            "question": {
                "english": "Please enter your systolic blood pressure.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446585795_Blood_Pressure_Kit.png",
            "iconSrc": "Blood Pressure",
            "view": "views/toggle-question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/finished",
            "toggle": {
                "value": 100,
                "max": 500,
                "min": 50,
                "high": {
                    "value": 150,
                    "message": "/message/5"
                },
                "low": {
                    "value": 75,
                    "message": "/message/6"
                }
            }
        }],
        "messages": [{
            "url": "/message/1",
            "message": {
                "english": "Please talk to your nurse or doctor about why you do not want to.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/alert-red.png",
            "iconSrc": "Alert",
            "view": "views/message.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/message/2"
        }, {
            "url": "/message/2",
            "message": {
                "english": "Good job!",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446586860_Best_Choice.png",
            "iconSrc": "Thumbs Up!",
            "view": "views/message.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/1"
        }, {
            "url": "/home",
            "title": {
                "english": "Thank you for being part of today.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "subtitle": {
                "english": "Remember this device does not take place of a personal emergency response system or a call to 911.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "view": "views/home.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/1"
        }]
    }
}
```

Note: Just editted it to reflect the method I'm using to get the different lengths.

Comment: CNR for me. I get the length of three, when I console log it it's three, and when I look at it manually, it's three. Though: `console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions);` - I am using "HomeGateway", which you don't have written, but is a must with the code you provided.

Are there any other manipulations you're doing to this object that could affect it?

Comment: hi.. when you do console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions) and you inspect the object - what is the length of it?

Comment: Are you adding to the array after you log it? Arrays and objects in the console log are "live" -- if you change the object and inspect it in the console, you'll see the latest version.

Comment: Just figured out the problem - angular.bootstrap(document) is messing with the object for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

There is no `appData.questions`. It must be `appData.HomeGateway.questions` which gives three in both cases (of course it does). And here is a demo of your own data:

```js
var appData = {
    "HomeGateway": {
        "company": "",
        "title": {
            "english": "",
            "spanish": "",
            "russian": "",
            "otherlanguage": ""
        },
        "language": "english",
        "pressOKQuestion": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Press ",
                "spansih": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " to move to the next question",
                "spanish": "\" to move to the next question",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "pressOKMessage": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Press ",
                "spansih": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " to move on",
                "spanish": "\" to move to the next question",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "pressUpDown": {
            "left": {
                "english": "Please press ",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "middle": {
                "english": " or ",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "right": {
                "english": " on your remote control to select",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            }
        },
        "questions": [{
            "url": "/question/1",
            "question": {
                "english": "Have you talked to your doctor today?",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "view": "views/question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/2",
            "answers": [{
                "id": 1,
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Yes",
                    "spanish": "Si",
                    "russian": ""
                }
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "No",
                    "spanish": "No",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "message": "/message/3"
            }]
        }, {
            "url": "/question/2",
            "question": {
                "english": "On a scale of 0-10, how bad is your pain today?",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446585749_Doctor_Consultation.png",
            "iconSrc": "Broken Arm",
            "view": "views/question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/3",
            "answers": [{
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Low",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "1-2"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Medium",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "3-4"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "High",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "5-8",
                "message": "/message/4"
            }, {
                "answer": {
                    "english": "Very High",
                    "spanish": "",
                    "russian": ""
                },
                "category": "9-10",
                "message": "/message/4"
            }]

        }, {
            "url": "/question/3",
            "question": {
                "english": "Please enter your systolic blood pressure.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446585795_Blood_Pressure_Kit.png",
            "iconSrc": "Blood Pressure",
            "view": "views/toggle-question.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/finished",
            "toggle": {
                "value": 100,
                "max": 500,
                "min": 50,
                "high": {
                    "value": 150,
                    "message": "/message/5"
                },
                "low": {
                    "value": 75,
                    "message": "/message/6"
                }
            }
        }],
        "messages": [{
            "url": "/message/1",
            "message": {
                "english": "Please talk to your nurse or doctor about why you do not want to.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/alert-red.png",
            "iconSrc": "Alert",
            "view": "views/message.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/message/2"
        }, {
            "url": "/message/2",
            "message": {
                "english": "Good job!",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "icon": "img/icons/1446586860_Best_Choice.png",
            "iconSrc": "Thumbs Up!",
            "view": "views/message.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/1"
        }, {
            "url": "/home",
            "title": {
                "english": "Thank you for being part of today.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "subtitle": {
                "english": "Remember this device does not take place of a personal emergency response system or a call to 911.",
                "spanish": "",
                "russian": ""
            },
            "view": "views/home.html",
            "controller": "loadData",
            "nextPage": "#/question/1"
        }]
    }
};

document.write(appData.HomeGateway.questions.length);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(appData.HomeGateway.questions);
console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions.length);
console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions);
```

Comment: hi.. when you do console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions) and you inspect the object - what is the length of it?

Comment: Same thing: 3. I used `document.write()` because it is easier for the demo, but I will update my answer and add `console.log` too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are skipping a key in the second console.log

Assuming this is not actual code, but written for us, I am assuming you missed the questions key in your second console. It may look like this

```
console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions.length)

console.log(appData.HomeGateway)
```

Comment: hi.. when you do console.log(appData.HomeGateway.questions) and you inspect the object - what is the length of it?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object] : 3